# Can users manipulate values from read-only fields using javascript or any other way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have simple html form below that has the regno field  set as readonly.Is it possible for any user to  some way change the value that are being sent?

I read about XSS attacks how scripts are submitted in user forms to steal cookies etc... so is it also possible for users to manipulate the values that are submitted in read-only field of forms.

here is my sample code

```
Register Number :<input type="text" name="regno" value="007" readonly = "readonly" />
```

and a sample php code to display values.

```
<?php
   foreach($_POST as $value){
     $str=htmlspecialchars(trim($value));
     echo $str;
   }
?>
```

is it possible for users to still manipulate the value?

Comment: Yes it is, they can remove the readonly attributes in multiple ways. Best way would be sessions where you store the number or make some kind of hash with salt and send it as a hidden field too, so you can validate the number.

Comment: To prevent simple xss attacks is using htmlspeacialchars enough?

Comment: hash salt :( I`m newbie i just know that salt is something thats added before or after a password and then its encrypted using one of php`s built-in encryption techniques...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can a regular user with no malicious intent change the value of a read only input? No.

Malicious user, however, can *always* post *any* arbitrary data regardless of how your form looks which is why you *always* validate user input on the server and *never* rely on client-side code alone for validation.